# Ubuntu can not detect my sd card

Tags: drivers, mount, sd-card

Here is the problem.
My SD card isn't recognized on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
When running:

```
dmesg|tail
[  908.892383] mmc0: error -110 whilst initializing SD card
[  910.224385] mmc0: error -110 whilst initializing SD card
[  955.181243] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[  955.181244] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[ 1233.158393] mmc0: error -110 whilst initializing SD card
[ 1234.494488] mmc0: error -110 whilst initializing SD card
[ 1235.826385] mmc0: error -110 whilst initializing SD card
[ 1389.058881] mmc0: error -110 whilst initializing SD card
[ 1390.394888] mmc0: error -110 whilst initializing SD card
[ 1391.730796] mmc0: error -110 whilst initializing SD card
```

I have this error.

Comment: Is this card readable on any other computer and/or operating system and/or card reader? If not, the card itself is probably broken, but it could also be a broken card reader or missing driver support.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes the card works on an other computer with windows 10 I will check for any missing driver but I think everything is installed. I will try to use an other sd card to verify if sd card reader is broken. And I will get back to you

Comment: Got the same error `mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card` with a 128 GB SD card on Fedora 27 with kernel `4.16.7-200.fc27.x86_64` and the latest BIOS on a Thinkpad T450s using its built-in card reader. On the *same machine* the *same card* mounts and reads correctly under Windows 10. So it is not a hardware for firmware issue.

Comment: I tried all I could but could not resolve this issue with the little knowledge I have .